# DataTable Sortable with dynamic data source

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable

I have a table with events between 'Time1' and 'Time2'.

On click on 'Load' the data will be loaded by a ajax function, with some parameter.

Now I want to use a sortable table...[DataTable](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html)

The Table initialize correct. But if I add the rows with

```
$('table').append('<tr><td> ' + row.id + '</td><td>' + row.name + '</td></tr>');
```

I can not sort the table.

How I can realize it with Ajax to make the table sortable? I dont know how the [DataTable Manual](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html) means it

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="report-table" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="report">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And the Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dataset = null;

    $('#report-table').dataTable({
        data: dataset,
        columns: [
            { title: 'ID' },
            { title: 'Name' }
        ]   
    });

    $('#btn-load, .btn-filter-apply').on('click', function() {
        $('#filter').modal('hide');     

        var data = new Array();
        $('.filter-list tr').each(function(idx, row) {
            data.push([$(row).find('td').eq(0).text(), $(row).find('td').eq(1).text(), $(row).find('td').eq(2).text()]);
        });

        $.post('/data', { from: $('#ipDateTimeFrom').val(), till: $('#ipDateTimeTo').val(), data: data, ip: $('#sb-server option:selected').val() }, function(resp) {
            $('#report').html('');
            dataset = resp.data;
            $.each(resp.data, function(idx, row) {
                $('#report').append('<tr style="background-color:#ffffff"><td>' + row.ID + '</td><td>' + row.Name + '</td></tr>');
            });     
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: provide your html and js code so that one can check and help

Comment: I add the Code to my post, but I dont know how to solve. I think my QC is not very helpful :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [`dataTable.row.add()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add%28%29) and [`dataTable.order()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/order%28%29) - you shouldn't need AJAX to reorder the dataTable. **EDIT** Please note this requires you follow the proper `dataTable` convention of adding data tow the table using the `dataTable.row.add()` method, hence including that in the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dataset = null;

  // Table represented as var table.
  var table = $('#report-table').DataTable({
    data: dataset,
    columns: [{
      title: 'ID'
    }, {
      title: 'Name'
    }]
  });

  var rowData = [ "id", "title" ];

  // Add an array of row data, e.g., [ "id", "title" ], have to redraw
  // when we modify table.
  table.row.add(rowData).draw(false);

  $('#btn-load, .btn-filter-apply').on('click', function() {
    $('#filter').modal('hide');

    var data = new Array();
    $('.filter-list tr').each(function(idx, row) {
      data.push([$(row).find('td').eq(0).text(), $(row).find('td').eq(1).text(), $(row).find('td').eq(2).text()]);
    });

    // Order based on index - maybe you can use your mysterious
    # $("filter-list tr") query above to order more dynamically
    table.order([1, 'asc'], [2, 'asc']).draw();
  });
});
```

Also note that you can source data from an AJAX source in the initializer as follows, if you wish:

```
$('#report-table').dataTable( {
  "ajax": "data.json"
});
```

**EDIT**: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sd6UQ/256/).

Comment: I get an error if I try to add something.
`Cannot read property 'add' of undefined`
My dataTable Version is 1.10.7

Comment: I found the problem.
With `var table = $('#report-table').dataTable` it didn't work. But with a big D at the beginn it works `var table = $('#report-table').DataTable` Thanks for your help

Comment: @nagazi Literally just updated that. It's the old syntax, pre `v1.10`, which shows how long ago I used DataTables...